# How to access views added programmatically to a custom view?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom class that extends from the MaterialCardView class, to which I add a TextView programmatically like this:

```
public class CustomQuestionView  extends MaterialCardView {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public TextView timeTextView;
    

  public CustomQuestionView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        this.linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalContentXLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        horizontalContentXLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        this.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalContentXLayoutParams);
        this.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        this.addView(linearLayout);

        this.timeTextView = new TextView(context);
        this.timeTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.timeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfc03"));
        this.timeTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
        this.timeTextView.setText("What is your name?");
        this.linearLayout.addView(timeTextView);


   linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    public CustomQuestionView (Context context){
        super(context);
    }


    public void setQuestion(String question){
        this.timeTextView.setText(question);
    }


}
```

I create an instance of the CustomQuestionView in the onViewCreated() method of my fragment like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        customQuestionView = new CustomQuestionView(requireContext());
      //  customQuestionView.setQuestion("Is this my custom question?");
        
    }
```

And my XML code for my fragment where the custom view is looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".customviews.CustomViewsFragment">
    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Welcome!"/>
        
        <com.pedroprojects.adc2.customviews.CustomQuestionView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>
    
</FrameLayout>
```

The CustomQuestionView is created, and I get the initial text on the TextView showing on screen if I don't make a call to the setQuestion() method, but the problem is that when I try to change the text by calling the setQuestion() method (when I uncomment the commented line on my onViewCreated() method), the app crashes and gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.pedroprojects.adc2.customviews.CustomQuestionView.setQuestion(CustomQuestionView.java:74)
        at com.pedroprojects.adc2.customviews.CustomViewsFragment.onViewCreated(CustomViewsFragment.java:51)
```

Why is my TextView null at the moment of invocation of this method, if I assign a value to it in the constructor? How do I need to access this TextView so that I can modify it after the CustomQuestionView is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the constructor where you are initializing the TextView is not invoked but rather the other constructor. So the `timeTextView` is null and when you try to invoke `customQuestionView.setQuestion` it causes a `NullPointerException` and crashes.

Comment: Thank you! I copied my code from my `CustomQuestionView (Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)` constructor to my `CustomQuestionView(Context context)` constructor, and now the app doesn't crash when I call the `CustomQuestionView.setQuestion()` method, but the text doesn't get updated either. Do you know what could be causing the problem?

Comment: The other constructor is called, you are right about it but its called via the xml. When you programmatically call the  `customQuestionView = new CustomQuestionView(requireContext());` the instance variables of the class are set to default value. Thus means that the `timeTextView` is null as the TextView is never initialized programatically. And when you call `CustomQuestionView.setQuestion()` it causes a `NullPointerException`

Comment: The reason why the text is not getting updated is that the programmatically added view is not added to the layout. You are creating two `CustomQuestionView` one via xml and one progrmatically. If you want to update the text you add an `id` to the element in the xml and do a `findViewById` as you would do normally. Then call the `setQuestion()` on that instance of the `CustomQuestionView`. This should work.

Comment: You're right, the constructor with 2 parameters is called via XML, and after doing some more testing, I realized that I don't need the `CustomQuestionView(Context context)` constructor. All I did was to add an id to my custom view in my XML file, and then initialize it on my fragment code like: `customQuestionView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_custom_view_id);` instead of doing the `customQuestionView = new CustomQuestionView(requireContext());` and now it's working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroOrellana If would be great to accept the answer if you found it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should choose the method of creating your custom view: in code or in xml. Views have different constructors for different creation methods.
You have implementation only in constructor for creation from xml, but when you create view from code, you does not initialise linearlayout and button, so your should initvialise it too in your CustomQuestionView(Context context) constructor, so you have your null.
And when you make your view from code, you should create your view in onCreateView method and add it in your fragment root view. And then change question in your onViewCreated method.